# What's the right way to build Java Map that is a HashMap but converts values on input and output?

Tags: java, dictionary, wrapper

I basically need a slightly modified version of a `HashMap` where whenever a value is read or written it needs to be converted. So far I have tried the following:

```
public class MyMap implements Map<String, Object> {

    private HashMap<String, MyType> map;

    public Object get(Object key) {
        return map.get(key).getValue();
    }

    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        return map.put(key, MyType.wrap(value)).getValue();
    }

    ... all other methods of the Map interface are handled by map
}
```

I was hoping that was all I needed to do, but I am struggling with those two methods:

```
Set<Entry<String,Object>> entrySet()
Collection<Object> values()
```

Those I can't just forward to map as the values need to be converted one by one. Of course I could basically copy the implementation from HashMap and modify it to fit my needs, but that seemed to be rather ugly solution and I before I do that I wanted to make sure I am not missing a much nicer solution.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Why can't you just stop the wrapping values in the map directly?

Comment: It think this whole pattern is pretty ugly

Comment: The reason why I can't do that is, that getValue() actually retrieves the value from some changeable source. If I would put the retrieved values directly in the map they wouldn't be updated anymore.

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap the hashmap in a class and expose method on that class to add or remove.

like this

```
Class MyHashmap {

private Map map = new HashMap();

//methods for add/remove to wrap and put in HashMap
public void add(String ,Object) {
  map.put(key, MyType.wrap(value)).getValue();

}
```

//same way you can add method for remove.

Comment: but that way MyHasmap doesn't implement the Map interface, which I would like to

Comment: another way could be to move the conversion logic to the class of objects which you are trying to put on map, if that is known.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache Commons [TransformedMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/TransformedMap.html) and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: that looks similar to what I need, but it only transforms new objects added, while I also want a transformation when object are being read...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is per se quite ugly, so I wouldn't worry to death about a slightly ugly implementation. Either do what you're suggesting, or else make the get/put methods put the converted values in the map, and then the other methods are just simple wrappers.

Comment: I can't do the second suggestion, see comment #3 to my question post

Comment: OK, then I think you're back to the solution of copying the general pattern of the standard HashMap implementations, but adding your conversion in the relevant places.